# Replace all words contained in my column of texts in my data frame with numbers from a dictionary

Tags: python, regex, replace

I have a dictionary of keys and values, tokens and integers(magnitude of the vector for each word).  I want to search through a text column of my dataframe and replace each matching word(tokens) with the corresponding value from my dictionary(integers).  How would I replace all of the text in the dataframe with it's corresponding value in my dictionary using regex?

my_dict = {"hey": 1, "bad":-1, "good":2}

0   That is good to know,

1   That was a bad game

The goal of my result would be

0   That is 2 to know,

1   That was a -1 game

I would actually be even better if I could remove all the text together and just get a list of numbers for each row to replace the original text like the result below:

0   [2]

1   [-1]

Comment: Did my answer help @acodrjdatam? Don't forget to upvote and accept if so, thank you! :)

Comment: What if a word appears twice? Should the corresponding value also appear twice in the result?

Comment: If a word appears twice, the number should appear twice in the list. So if "good," appears twice in the text, I would like to see [2,2] in my corresponding list of numbers for that row.